# How can I link external files to eclipse in php and force it to copy to my project folder?

Tags: php, eclipse

I use ecplise for my php projects.

I want to have an external location for all my plugins and link specific plugins to each of my projects.

I found how to link folders etc, but the actual files aren't copied in the folder, resulting in errors in the website because the files are missing. They are only inside my project.

How can I link an actual folder to my eclipse project, that is being updated automatically from the source?

In Visual Studio there is an option to copy specific resources to the output folder. I am looking for something similar here.

Answer (score 0):

Some things come to mind:

1. I don't know if such an option exists. You could achieve that with build tools, that just to the copy on build. You wouldn't then need to reference the files in eclipse any longer then however.
2. You can configure the PHP include path in your project. Then you can configure the include in your application the same. Might not solve all your issues, but would work cross compatible.